# GZIP and javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, gzip

I have a 80 kB javascript file, and I made some tests and concluded that after gzipping the size will be reduced to 34 kB.

I have googled 100 times and asked many people and they give me links like [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/speed-up-apache-20-web-access-or-downloads-with-mod_deflate.html) and [this one](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_deflate.html) Even after rereading them, I still can't gzip the js file.

Can someone explain a good place to start and where to go from there? I think I'll need to change something in .htaccess file, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The links you were given are correct.  You may need to add `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript` as well, or some other mimetype that your server might be serving your .js file as.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you actually have access to your apache instance or are you hosted and only able to change the .htaccess?

Comment: no, I have installed apache for windows, but it works only in localhost

Comment: All these changes go in `httpd.conf`

Comment: how (and where) to create that file...

Comment: It's in your `apache/conf` folder.  Chances are apache is in your program files folder.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1047878/how-to-make-webpage-with-gzip?rq=1

Comment: Yes I found it
Computer\ C\ X\ Apache\ Conf\

Comment: @Amden is your server a windows box or linux?

Comment: "free hosting" is not a kind of "operating system". what kind of access do you have to the server?

Comment: And what kind of access do you have to it? Can you edit the httpd.conf file there, or you just have a website folder? if you do, the second link you posted contains almost exactly the code you need to add there, with the difference being that you need to add `text/javascript` to the list of mime-types to use `DEFLATE` on...

Comment: I have just the public_html folder and inside it I have .htaccess

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file you should be able to put in something like

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

This does depend on if the web host allows .htaccess files and other security settings.